# I am having trouble getting the data I need from the taobot_voltage_listener object, any alternative to binding?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I used roslibjs-client library from npm to create a listener that listens to a rostopic and get the float32 data (message.data) from it. I need to use the message.data from the listener in taobot_voltage_listener to setState the battery to display it on the app. So far, I tried to bind taobot-voltage_listener but I received an error
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined
Is this due to me using window.RosClient and window.EventEmitter2 in the require?
How can I set the object properly?
Or is there an alternative that allows me to not bind the onject but still allows me to set state?
Another question is how do I make a callback function for taobot_voltage_listener?

The code is below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
window.EventEmitter2 = require('eventemitter2');
window.RosClient = require('roslibjs-client');

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      date: new Date(),
      battery: 0
    };
    this.taobot_voltage_listener = this.taobot_voltage_listener.bind(this);

  }

  componentWillMount() {
    var client = new window.RosClient({
      url: "ws://172.20.243.144:9090"
    });
    console.log("Client is ");
    console.log(client);

    var batt = 0;

    var taobot_voltage_listener = client.topic.subscribe('/taobot_voltage_listener', 'std_msgs/Float32', function(message){
      console.log('Received message on ' + taobot_voltage_listener.name + ': ' + message.data);
      console.log(typeof message.data);
      batt = message.data;
      console.log(batt);
      //this.setState({battery: message.data});

    });
  }

//Sets the interval for each refresh
  componentDidMount() {
    this.timerID = setInterval(
      () => this.tick(),
      10000
    );
  }



  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.timerID);
  }

//Get new time stamp
  tick() {
    this.setState({
      date: new Date(),
      //battery: new taobot_voltage_listener()
    });
  }



  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
        </header>
        <p className="App-intro">
          To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <p className="Date Time">
          it is {this.state.date.toLocaleTimeString()}
        </p>
        <p className="Battery-state">
          Battery has {this.state.battery}
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are missing the `bind` of your functions.

The method `this.nameFunction = this.nameFunction.bind(this);` can be transformed for `nameFunction = (parametersIfThereIs) => {...}`

```js
componentDidMount = () => {
  this.timerID = setInterval(
    () => this.tick(),
    10000
  );
}

componentWillUnmount = () => {
  clearInterval(this.timerID);
}

//Get new time stamp
tick = () => {
  this.setState({
    date: new Date(),
    //battery: new taobot_voltage_listener()
  });
}
```

See if it works.